# MVVM - Set datagrid with combobox contains flag enum values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, wpf-controls

How can I binding Combobox to flag enum values with checkbox's and labels?

for example I have flags enum of week days:

```
[Flags]
public enum WeekDays
{
    None = 0,
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}
```

Person class:

```
    public class Worker : ViewModelBase
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Name); }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Age); }
        }

        private WeekDays _workingDays;

        public WeekDays WorkingDays
        {
            get { return _workingDays; }
            set { _workingDays = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => WorkingDays); }
        }
    }
```

And my ViewModel contain a collection of worker and collection WeekDays(enum with text):

```
public class VM : ViewModelBase
{
    public VM()
    {
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Sunday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Sunday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Monday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Monday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Tuesday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Tuesday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Wednesday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Wednesday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Thursday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Thursday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Friday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Friday });
        EnumWrapperCollection.Add(new WorkerEnumWrapper() { Name = "Saturday", BitEnum = WeekDays.Saturday });

        Workers.Add(new Worker() { Name = "Steve", Age = 34, WorkingDays = WeekDays.Sunday | WeekDays.Monday });
        Workers.Add(new Worker() { Name = "John", Age = 52, WorkingDays = WeekDays.Wednesday | WeekDays.Friday });

        SelectWorker = Workers.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<WorkerEnumWrapper> _enumsWrapperCollection = new ObservableCollection<WorkerEnumWrapper>();

    public ObservableCollection<WorkerEnumWrapper> EnumWrapperCollection
    {
        get { return _enumsWrapperCollection; }
        set { _enumsWrapperCollection = value; }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Worker> _workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>();
    public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
    {
        get { return _workers; }
        set { _workers = value; }
    }

    private Worker _selectWorker;

    public Worker SelectWorker
    {
        get { return _selectWorker; }
        set { _selectWorker = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectWorker); }
    }
}
```

My xmal Window contains a DataGrid of Workers and a Combobox with workdays by the collection of EnumWrapperCollection. Each line of worker with the ComboBox need to contain all the week days but only the "WorkingDays" of the Worker will be checked. Also I want that the user will be able to check and uncheck the workdays and change the value by doing that.

The window should look like that:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I tried to create a combobox that all the values are the "EnumWrapperCollection" (Sunday, Monday etc.). The ItemTemplate/DataTemplate is Checkbox and Label. The Label is set to Name(Sunday, Monday etc.) and the checkbox is set by converter that get the value that been selected (Worker) and the Bitmap of the WorkerEnumWrapper and return true if the SelectWorker.WorkDays contain the flag at the WorkerEnumWrapper and false if not. The convertion in checking the checkbox is getting same values and change the SelectedWorker.WorkDays by the current selection.